# How does an epicyclic differential split torque?

Tags: torque, differential, theory

How does an epicyclic differential split torque even when rotating as a single locked unit with no relative motion between its parts? Should it not have 50/50 torque split because its all rotating as one unit? How can it achieve torque bias like that

Comment: In what kind of application are you talking about? I'm not aware of any differentials which directly use epicyclic gears (also known as *planetary* gears), though it doesn't mean they don't exist. In vehicles, they are often used at the wheel for gear reduction. They're also used in transmissions for the same reason. Can you give me an example of a vehicle today using an epicyclic differential (or one considering it)?

Comment: Today i dont know, but i can give you a lot of old examples. AWD Porsche 964, lancia delta s4 , lancia delta integrale, Alfa romeo 155 DTM, Ferrari 408 4RM all with a center epicyclic differential and viscous coupling to limit the slip. However an epicyclic differential when it doesnt have any limited slip device connected to it always splits the torque by a fixed amount like regular open diff but it differs from them by being able to bias the torque. Bias never changes because its open diff but with a planetary it does not have to be 50/50 torque split like in regular open diff

Comment: I take it, then, you're actually referring to the center differential, which many would call a transfer case or transaxle? In the case of a transaxle, I'm not seeing the planetary being used in the differential to change the direction of power out to the wheels.

Comment: i wouldnt call it a transaxle. For example yeah porsche calls the 964s system a longitudinal transfer case with a planetary differential in it. When the driver did not press the "lock" button, Its a completely open planetary center differential always splits the torque 69 rear 31 front no matter the amount of slip. Its always 69/31 both when driving straight happily and when it also slips unlike a regular open diff that always splits torque by 50/50 and cant bias the distribution.

Comment: For example you can see planetary center diffs in this video as well but the presenter doesnt do a good job of describing why the torque split is biased even in no slip situation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRmwHEjEyVM&t=0s , Also a link for the 964 system https://newsroom.porsche.com/en/history/porsche-all-wheel-drive-milestones-lohner-porsche-cisitalia-racing-car-carrera-4-viscous-coupling-porsche-traction-management-ptm-911-turbo-15046.html

Comment: According to [this explanation](https://www.awdwiki.com/images/porsche-911-carrera-4-964-center-differential.jpg), the Porsche's bias of 31/69 is there until the front tires start to slip, then a hydraulically controlled coupling (clutch) engages. To me, it doesn't look like the planetary gears have much, if anything, to do with the torque biasing going on, but rather is just a ratio change. The torque biasing occurs up front where the clutches for the coupling reside.

Comment: No, it clearly says that when the lock mode is disengaged these hydraulic clutches dont do anything and the torque is ALWAYS split 69/31 no matter what because its an open differential when the lock mode is not engaged. Here im directly quoting them "provided the lock control is not enabled, it is always split in the same ratio: 69 per cent for the rear axle, 31 per cent forwards via an enclosed transaxle shaft."

Comment: You can watch the other video i sent made by an ex f1 engineer, im pretty sure he is right but  he does not do such  a good job at explaining how exactly this torque splitting nature of the planetary differential works even when there is no slip and that is what im wondering

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you about the torque split until slippage. I'm just not seeing as how the planetary can be providing the torque split, as all it does is change the gear ratio (as far as I can tell). After watching the Kyle Engineer video, I see there must be a way the planetary is providing the torque split, but he glosses over that part of how it actually does what it's doing. When I get home this afternoon, I'll do some more research.

Comment: Alright, i tried looking as well but i could not really find anything. There is a forum and a guy posted a link  of Lancia Delta integrale workshop manual that apperantly shows how exactly that happens but the forum is from 12 years ago and link for pdf is expired and couldnt find anything outside of that. forum link https://forums.autosport.com/topic/159097-planetary-centre-diffs-with-uneven-torque-distribution/

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Hello again, i found that "expired link" that i was talking about. It explains very well how the center planetary differential unevenly distributes the torque. Here is the link if you are also still interested. You can find it in pages 153-155 https://procarmanuals.com/wp-content/uploads/pdfs/manuals/lancia-delta-integrale-4wd-workshop-manual_part1.pdf